# how to define value type when using keyof (typescript)

Tags: typescript, generics, types, key-value, typeof

I have an interface like so:

```
interface SearchListProps<T extends object, K extends keyof T> {
    data: T[];
    sort_and_filter_key: K;
}
```

In this interface i have the property `sort_and_filter_key` which can only be a key of the supplied generic object. But this still allows for the possibility that the value of this key can be anything. But i would like to limit the options for this value to only be `strings`.

So the following would be valid:

```
interface Test {
    a: string, 
    b: number,
    c: object
}

const objectB: SearchListProps<Test, keyof Test> = {
    data: [{ a: "as", b: 1, c: {} }],
    sort_and_filter_key: "a", // true
}
```

Since in the example above the value of `sort_and_filter_key` is a string

and this would be invalid:

```
const objectA: SearchListProps<Test, keyof Test> = {
    data: [{ a: "as", b: 1, c: {} }],
    sort_and_filter_key: "b", // false
}
```

Since here the value of `sort_and_filter_key` is a number.

Is this possible with a generic definition?

Comment: See the linked questions and their answers for more information.  You can use the `KeysMatching<T, V>` definition in there to write `K extends KeysMatching<T, string>`, although you might be ultimately happier reversing the constraint to `K extends keyof T, T extends Record<K, string>`.